# adding custom header with classic asp

Tags: asp-classic

I was wondering if its possible to add custom header with classic asp. In other words, I am looking for classic asp equivalent of .net's Response.AddHeader().

i.e.
HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("customheadertruefalse","1");

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `Response.AddHeader` (as JohnFx already answered). 
Here is sample from one of my working asp pages :

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=ranking-export.csv"
```

Comment: is there a way to add some response header to responses from asp pages ? like asp.net has customer header section.

Answer (score 4):

Don't mean to be that guy, but have you tried [Response.AddHeader](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_addheader.asp)?